# Asp.Net Model validation with Regex. Looking for specific string not just a letter

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I am currently in a situation where we do not want to allow outside emails for one of our applications. The application is developed in Asp.Net MVC. I am aware that on the model side you can do server side validation which you can then use to get front end validation. My problem is that the RegularExpression I use always returns true as if it is only looking for one of those letters not the whole string. How can I make it look for the whole string?

Here is an example code snippet and result.

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
//I have tried many different variations on the regex
[RegularExpression("{/@gmail}", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]
//[RegularExpression("{[/@gmail]}", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]
//[RegularExpression("{[/@][g][m][a][i][l]}", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]
//[RegularExpression("/@gmail", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]

public string Email {get; set;}
```

This seems to be the result no matter what variation I try on the regex.
I also read through all the rules and I didn't see anything for matching a string.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Uqw.png)

Very stumped....
In perl it would be as simple as "s/@gmail//g", is there nothing similar that can be done from the model side?

@PeterB

```
[RegularExpression("@gmail", ErrorMessage = "Please do not use your gmail account.")]
```

[Result using the gmail format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Uqw.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.net, but do you need to use brackets at all here?? Does `RegularExpression("@gmail"....` not work?

Comment: I tried this as well but had no luck, it seems to be searching for one of those letters rather than the literal string value.

Comment: Erm... I doubt it... Are you sure you restarted the server/etc after saving something like `[/@gmail]` - which *would* behave like that, due to the special meaning of square brackets in regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, I am working in visual studio locally, so anytime I stop debugging to make a change, save changes, then debug it restarts the local server

Comment: Tried `[RegularExpression("@gmail", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]` yet?

Comment: Without escaping the @?

Comment: Regardless I just tried both ways with the same result....

Comment: Can you please just do a sanity check here... Delete that validation, or change it to something completely different, and see what validation errors still appear. I am not convinced that the server is picking up the change; or perhaps you are testing on the wrong server.

Comment: `[RegularExpression("")]` tells what format is REQUIRED. Not the format that is FORBIDDEN. The ErrorMessage shows when input does not match the REQUIRED format.

Comment: @TomLord I did and yes I'm sure I'm just testing it on Visual studios local server so I'm positive I'm not on the wrong server and that it is restarting on each run.

Comment: @PeterB Ah! I had that suspicion. Is there a way to say the opposite? something like [RegularExpression(!"")] or something to that effect"

Comment: @PeterB I thought I tested that because I thought the same thing. So I just tested it with a gmail account with the same error...?

Comment: you need to eliminate the @gmail string from the regex, check this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: @NoorSamara Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed. Although I don't understand the format... The solution was `^((?!gmail).)*$`

Comment: Great Community thank you for all the help, been stuck on this for a full day now -_-

Comment: Be careful with that pattern, it will also deny e.g. `dogmaillusion@ok.com`

Comment: @PeterB I changed it to `^((?!@gmail).)*$` that should handle that issue. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your original understanding, the answer *would* have been to use:

```
[RegularExpression("@gmail", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]
```

However, this validation rule actually states that the email *must* contain `"@gmail"`, not *must not* contain.

The solution, then, is to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to negate the pattern - something like:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!.*@gmail)", ErrorMessage = "No Gmail accounts allowed")]
```

This is saying "looking ahead from the start of the string, it *cannot* contain the pattern: `"@gmail"`".

Comment: Also worth noting: You should probably block `@googlemail` too, as that would be a trivial way to bypass your check :)